# Finite Intersection Property implies compactness?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, complex-analysis, compactness

I am having trouble proving this statement (from *Conway. Functions of one complex variable*)

> If $\mathcal{F}$ is a collection of closed subsets of $K\subseteq X$ which satisfies the f.i.p. and $\bigcap\{F:F\in \mathcal{F}\}\neq\emptyset$ then $K$ is compact.

I tried a proof by contradiction with $K$ supposed not compact. Then it exists an open covering $\mathcal{G}$ which does not contain a finite subcover of $K$. From this point, i thought i could build up a collection of closed sets by taking the complements of the open covering $\mathcal{G}$. But are those $X-G$ subsets of $K$? I mean, each $G\in\mathcal{G}$ is a subset of $K$, which made me believe that $X-G$ could not be possibly a subset of $K$. What's wrong?

Comment: As written, it's wrong. It should be something like "If $\bigcap \mathcal{F} \neq \varnothing$ for all families $\mathcal{F}$ of closed subsets of $K$ with the finite intersection property, then $K$ is compact."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not by contradiction but by contrapositive:

Let $\mathcal{U}$ be an open cover for $X$ (which satisfies the FIP property).
Then $\mathcal{F} = \{X\setminus U: U \in \mathcal{U}\}$ is a family of closed sets such that $\bigcap \mathcal{F} = X \setminus \bigcup \{U : U \in \mathcal{U}\}  =\emptyset$, by de Morgan. This means that $\mathcal{F}$ does **not** have the FIP.
So there exists finitely many $F_1 =X\setminus U_1, \ldots F_n = X\setminus U_n$ from $\mathcal{F}$ that have empty intersection. The $U_1,\ldots,U_n$ then form a finite subcover for $\mathcal{U}$ as required, again by de Morgan.

Comment: @FreeZe complement of an open set is closed.

Comment: @FreeZe The “world “ is $X$, of course.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $K$ has the finite intersection property. To prove that $K$ is compact let $\{U_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of open sets that cover $K$. We claim that this collection contains a finite subcollection of sets that also cover $K$. We prove this essentially using your idea of a contradiction.

Suppose that $K \neq\bigcup_{j \in J} U_j$ where $J\subset I$ is finite. Taking compliments gives $K^c \neq \bigcap U_j^c$, which by hypothesis is non-empty - since $U_i$ is open, $U_i^c$ is closed. Since $K$ has the fip we thus have that

$ \emptyset \neq \bigcap_{i \in I} U_i^c = \left( \bigcup_{i \in I} U_i \right)^c$. This contradicts $U_i$ being an open cover for $K$.