# Finite subcollection of formulae satisfying this property?

Tags: logic, model-theory

Fix $n>0$ and a complete theory $T$. Let $A_\phi$ denote the set of complete $n$-types of $T$ containing $\phi$.

Let $\{\phi_i\}_{i \in I}$ be a collection of formulae such that, for any complete $n$-type of $T$, call it $ \Sigma$, we have $\Sigma \in A_{\phi_i}$ for some $i \in I$.

> Q: Does there exist a finite subcollection $\{\phi_i\}_{i \in I'}$ satisfying the same property? (Namely, that for any complete $n$-type of $T$, call it $ \Sigma$, we have $\Sigma \in A_{\phi_i}$ for some $i \in I'$?)

The fact that we have a collection of formulae and we want a finite subcollection makes me suspect that Compactness is probably going to be the key ingredient here. But I don't know where to apply it. Certainly not to $\{\phi_i\}_{i \in I}$ itself, for it isn't even satisfiable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.

Recall the set of complete $n$-types $S_n$ can be given the **stone topology**, where the basic open sets are exactly your $A_\varphi$ for each formula $\varphi$. See [here](https://modeltheory.fandom.com/wiki/Type#The_space_of_complete_types), say.
It's well known that with this topology $S_n$ is compact, hausdorff, and totally disconnected.

Now you're asking if we have some family of basic opens $\{A_\varphi\}$ covering $S_n$, whether there is a finite subfamily which also covers $S_n$, and of course the answer is "yes"!
So you're right, that the claim follows from compactness, but possibly not the compactness you were thinking of ;).

(Of course I kid, the two notions of compactness are closely related)

---

I hope this helps ^_^

Comment: +1 I knew about this topology but didn't know the name of it, so thanks for that. I'm actually trying to prove a lemma to show $S_n$ is compact (or is there an easier way?) so of course I can't assume the thing I'm trying to prove

Comment: Imo the quickest way to show $S_n$ is compact is to check the [finite intersection property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_intersection_property). That is, $S_n$ is compact if and only if: for every family of closed sets, if any finite subfamily has nonempty intersection, then the _entire_ family has nonempty intersection. But you can check that this really _is_ logical compactness (if you unwind the definitions it's saying that if every finite subset of formulas has a model, then there's a model of all the formulas)

Comment: Of course, you can unwind _this_ further to get a direct proof from open covers. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2507985/finite-intersection-property-implies-compactness) for instance.

Comment: Also, googling "typespace is compact" brings up [a proof](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Type_Space_is_Compact) ^_^.